# How to display all DataGrid ComboBoxCells as ComboBoxes when row is selected?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've created a `DataGrid` where the user has to make a selection in two comboboxes that are present in each row ( see img ).
Now I want to make this "neater". Let me explain with an example.

[image: img 1)]

The user has to select a value in the column category and size. These columns are combo boxes.
When you click the first time the row gets selected ( see img ).

[image: Row selected]

Add this point I would like to display the comboboxes as actual comboboxes. But as seen on the image they still look like empty text boxes.
Only when you click the cell again, the cell will look like a combobox.

Note: the category combobox will get a static list off value's and the size combobox will get a specific list of value's depending on the selection of the category combobox

[image: Cell clicked]

What I want to achieve is fewer clicks for the user. How can i display the comboxbox row's as actual comboboxes and sidestep the extra click necessary to select the column?

Xaml of the datagridview:

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="10,110,162,15" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="X Coord" Binding="{Binding xCoord}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Y Coord" Binding="{Binding yCoord}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rotation" Binding="{Binding Rotation}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="RefDes" Binding="{Binding RefDes}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="P/N" Binding="{Binding Number}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Package" Binding="{Binding Package}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Category" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Size" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Binding class:

```cs
public class Part
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string RefDes { get; set; }
    public string xCoord { get; set; }
    public string yCoord { get; set; }
    public string Package { get; set; }
    public string Rotation { get; set; }
}

dataGrid.ItemsSource = cadFile.MatchList;
```

Comment: At this moment there is no data inside combobxes right ? Meaby thats the problem, put some dummy data and check. Out of record, I love to see when someone is dealing with SMT :)

Comment: @KubaDo
Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly this didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create your own `DataGrid` column template that displays:

- a `ComboBox` when the parent `DataGridRow` is selected,
- a `TextBlock` when the parent `DataGridRow` is not selected.

You can achieve this using [`DataGridTemplateColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn?view=netframework-4.8):

```xml
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Category" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Category, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryChoices}">
                    <ComboBox.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=IsSelected}"
                                             Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ComboBox.Style>
                </ComboBox>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=IsSelected}"
                                             Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

You also should add the `SelectionUnit="FullRow"` markup to your `DataGrid`. If you do not wish to do that, then you should change `AncestorType=DataGridRow` into `AncestorType=DataGridCell` to detect selection of cell instead of row.

Note that I've added the `CategoryChoices` property in each item for illustration purposes:

```cs
public IList<string> CategoryChoices { get; } = new List<string> { "Category1", "Category2" };
```

The result is:

[image: screen-snapshot]

Comment: I've replaced my column with your XAML code and this is the result and it doesn't seem to work. I've tried adding a picture but it seems I can't in a comment.
But the only change now is that the cell's in that collumn are displaying (collection) in them.

Comment: I've added a gif screenshot, how is that different from what you have?

Comment: In the Category Column all I see is ( Verzameling ) what is dutch for collection

Comment: I see you created your list diffrent then me let me alter that

Comment: It's still the same for me. If you want i can share more of the code but not sure what the best way is. Edit the question or upload somewhere else?

Comment: Do you have any errors popping in your output window? Any binding issue for example.

Comment: No , no error's are thrown or showing. I've edited my question to show my new XAML code

Comment: Can you show your view model class? The class that holds the `Category` , `CategoryChoices`, `X_coord`... properties.

Comment: You are missing a `Category` property in your class

Comment: public IList<string> Category { get; set; } added to the view model. Now i'm back at the same stiuation. Empty cell untill i click the cell then the combobox is shown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210148/discussion-between-corentin-pane-and-t-jasinski).